# North below south

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, geography, outer-space

> Mere me,
>   Cast second I,
>   Beg or bay,
>   Till softly I,
>   Leave with a coat on me.

Hint 1: Title knowledge

> The title refers to a geographical pair of the answer(s) in Ireland.

Hint 2: English geographical titbit

> An English county with four towns of population greater than 10 000 that are nouns also splits, with a space, into two more nouns. All nouns are common and found in Merriam-Webster.

Hint 3: Bear in mind that what

> Englishmen see as work, Americans see as fun.

Hint 4: I am a quarter longer in

> Ireland than in England, Scotland or Wales.

Comment: @Stiv the GM one would work with say shaw for hale which doesn't seem to be a noun in MW, though is elsewhere. It's not the one relevant to a line in the question. Hope it's your third one. Maybe I should strengthen Hint 2? (My one doesn't currently have an EPL team, but does have lower division teams.)

Comment: @Stiv, those first two counties are great finds, but can rule out Somerset as Bath is a city (tough!) and Greater Manchester only has Shaw, Lees and Sale as bury is a verb

Comment: @Stiv, ah Somerset is valid as has Minehead. I may try to rule out (though Hint 2 surely limits to a small number of counties/towns).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106397/discussion-between-stiv-and-tom).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle is:

> **LOUGH** (the Irish word for a body of water, like a ‘lake’ or ‘loch’)
>
>  <sup>This is supported by Hint 4, since the 5-letter word 'lough' is a quarter as long again as its 4-letter counterparts from England ('lake'), Wales ('llyn') or Scotland ('loch').</sup>

*Mere me,*

> A ‘[mere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mere_(lake))’ is a type of lake.  ‘Mere me’ could be taken to mean ‘I am a lake’...

*Cast second I,*

> This clues the word **SLOUGH**, which means '*cast* off' and can be made by adding the abbreviation 's' (meaning '*second*', a unit of time) to the front of the word 'lough'.
>  (i.e. Cast = second + I('me') = s + lough).
>
>  <sup>This word was further clued by Hint 2, being one of the many towns of the English county of *Berkshire* whose names can also be nouns. Others include Reading (e.g. a meter reading), Maidenhead and Ascot, possibly among others...</sup>

*Beg or bay,*

> Both of these are names of loughs in Ireland: [Lough Beg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lough_Beg) in Northern Ireland, and the very small [Bay Lough](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bay+Lough/@52.2497254,-7.9600081,15.5z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4843463a8f3a12df:0x9a776ef5c7f2808f!8m2!3d52.2505556!4d-7.9622222) in Tipperary, ROI. Note further that as well as being able to describe an inland body of water, a 'lough' can also be coastal and much more like a geographical 'bay' (consider [Belfast Lough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belfast_Lough), for example), stretching a long way along a coastline.

*Till softly I,*

> This clues the word **PLOUGH**, which means '*till*' and can be made by adding the musical abbreviation 'p' (meaning '*softly*') to the front of the word 'lough'.
>  (i.e. Till = softly + I('me') = p + lough).
>
>  <sup>This word was further clued by Hint 3, since the constellation Ursa Major is known to the English as 'The *Plough*' (a piece of farming equipment), whereas to Americans it is more commonly 'The Big Dipper' (a rollercoaster) - work vs play, indeed!</sup>

*Leave with a coat on me.*

> This clues the word **[FURLOUGH](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/furlough)**, which means '*leave*' (as in 'a leave of absence from a job') and can be made by adding a coat (or 'fur') to the front of the word 'lough'.
>  (i.e. Leave = coat + 'me' = fur + lough).

As for the title:

> This (as implied by Hint 1) refers to **[Lough Erne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lough_Erne)** in County Fermanagh, Northern Ireland. This lough is actually *two* connected lakes, and (oddly) the more *northern* of the two is known as '*the **Lower** Lough*' while the more *southern* of the two is known as '*the **Upper** Lough*'! Sounds like someone had their compass upside down when coming up with the names!

Comment: Excellent, all five lines are perfect!

Comment: rot13(Hccre naq ybjre jbhyq ersre gb nygvghqr, abguvat gb qb jvgu pbzcnff qverpgvbaf - gur bar arnere gur frn jvyy nyjnlf or gur ybjre)

Comment: @Mohirl I know, don't worry - that last comment is meant tongue-in-cheek ;-)